# Clone Sequel Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clone, sequel

I have a Model representing a Pricing Table with lots of entries and i want to offer the possibility to create a new Pricing with values from an existing entry.

Does anyone know how to do this, then Sequel is in use?

I tried dup and clone but in both cases the id is still there from the existing Model and thus will update the existing entry.

If i try to set the id by hand i get following error:

```
Sequel::InvalidValue: nil/NULL is not allowed for the id column
```

So i need a to find a Way to create a Model which is new but has prefilled values without having them to set in the code by hand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it:

```
new_pricing = Pricing.new(oldprice.attributes.tap{|attr| attr.delete("id")})
```

i get the attributes from the old model as hash, then remove the id and create a new Model by passing the attributes except the id.

Comment: how did you get the attributes ? there's no such method in Sequel::Model objects

Comment: ah sorry we have some kind of model which implements methods AR has but are missing in Sequel, try: values.with_indifferent_access

Answer (score -1):

The `model.attributes` solution didn't work for me. Sequel models have `to_hash` which is roughly equivalent, but `to_hash` doesn't return deserialized values. If you are using serializers (for `jsonb` fields, etc), simply passing a `to_hash` to `new` will fail because the values are not yet deserialized.

Here's the solution that works for me:

```
user = User.find(id: 123)

# freeze to avoid accidentally modifying the original user
user.freeze

# duplicate the record, deserialize values, and delete the primary key
# deserialization is useful if your model is using jsonb fields
record_copy = user.to_hash.merge(user.deserialized_values)
record_copy.delete(:id)

duplicate_user = User.new

# pass the has via `set_all` to avoid initialization callbacks
duplicate_user.set_all(record_copy)

# ... other important callbacks

duplicate_user.save
```